# ¿Como puedo calcular una columna "Edad" si tengo una fecha de nacimiento en Python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

La columna Nacimiento

`data2['Nacimiento'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['Nacimiento'])`

Le cambie el formato y me da tipo datetime64[ns]

```
hoy = date.today()
data2['edad'] = hoy.year - data2.Nacimiento.year - ((hoy.month, hoy.day) < (data2.Nacimiento.month, data2.Nacimiento.day))
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo porque quiero crear una nueva columna en el dataset que tenga que ver con la edad, dada la fecha de nacimiento.

Al tratar de crear la columna me da el error:
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'.`

De antemano gracias por las respuesta.

Comment: ejemplo del dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El error te sale porque la serie `data2.Nacimiento` no tiene el atributo `year`, es decir, la serie es de tipo `datetime` por lo que tiene el atributo `dt` y por lo tanto podrías obtener el año de la siguiente forma

```
data2['Nacimiento'].dt.year
```

Sin embargo hay una forma más fácil de hacer lo que deseas

Si no deseas agregar más librerías podrías utilizar la función `Timestamp` de pandas para obtener la fecha y hora actual

```
ahora = pd.Timestamp('now')
```

Y luego haces la resta entre "ahora" y la fecha de nacimiento, si agregas el método `astype()` puedes seleccionar el tipo de resultado, en este caso puedes configurar que el resultado lo de en años con `<m8[Y]`

```
data2['Edad'] = (ahora - data2['Nacimiento']).astype('<m8[Y]')
```

Si quieres seguir utilizando la librería `datetime` como lo muestras en tu pregunta entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
ahora = date.today()
data2['Edad'] = ahora.year - df['Nacimiento'].dt.year
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta, me sirvió mucho. Saludos