# Filtrado de fechas en python

Tags: python, pandas

estoy realizando un filtrado en una base de datos de productos.

En esta base de datos, el campo fecha lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde realizo una conversión a día/mes/año:

```
producto['insert_date'] = pd.to_datetime(producto['insert_date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Una vez lo tengo en este formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez ya lo tengo cambiado de formato, realizo un filtrado de fecha, pero no me lo realiza correctamente, ya que me devuelve un dataframe vacío:

```
filtered_df = producto.loc[(producto['insert_date'] >= '01/01/2022') & (producto['insert_date'] < '01/01/2022')]
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme en que me estoy equivocando?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estas haciendo la comparación con un string y deberías hacerlo con un objeto de tipo datetime o equivalente

Comment: Te refieres a la hora de hacer el filtered??

Comment: Buen día, como comentó Christian, es importante que el tipo de dato de la columna sea el correcto. Hay varias preguntas similares, por ejemplo [ésta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/569481/171630) o [ésta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/517254/171630) que pueden servirte como referencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu aproximación.

El primero de ellos es que al llamar a `dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`, lo que estás haciendo es convertir el tipo `datetime` a `string` (y guardándolo así en tu dataframe `producto`). Esto es incorrecto si posteriormente quieres realizar comparaciones, filtrados...etc, que necesiten una fecha. Deberías guardar la columna como un `datetime`, y usar una columna auxiliar o llamar al método `dt.strftime()` al vuelo si necesitas imprimir/guardar la fecha en un formato concreto.

Lo segundo es que estás tratando de filtrar tu dataframe utilizando un string ("01/01/2022"), pero lo que realmente quieres hacer es comparar objetos de tipo `datetime`, que son los que has de utilizar para comparar fechas. La comparación entre `strings` se realiza carácter a carácter, teniendo en cuenta el entero que corresponde a cada elemento. Un ejemplo para ilustrar:

```
'01/01/2022' > '01/01/2023' # False
'1/01/2022' > '01/01/2023' # True
```

Por lo tanto, lo primero que deberías hacer es almacenar tu columna como un objeto `datetime` (sin el `strftime`), y después filtrar con otro objeto `datetime`:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
# Definición del DF
...
producto['insert_date'] = pd.to_datetime(producto['insert_date'], format='%Y/%m/%d') # formato en el que tengas tu fecha en los datos
filtered_df = producto.loc[
    producto['insert_date'] > datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2022', '%d/%m/%Y'), # formato en el que hayas introducido la fecha filtro
]
```